Bode plotter, for audio frequency, using a precision sine generator, a precision RMS-to-DC IC's and a precision difference amplifier IC's
I'm trying to design an audio band bode plotter based on the block diagram of the image below.

The math behind is a subtraction of sine signals. The sine summation in equation 1 can be transformed into a subtraction (equation 2).
equation(1):
$$A\sin(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t + \alpha) = \sqrt{A^{2} + B^{2} + 2AB\cos(\alpha)} \sin(\omega t + \tan^{-1}(\frac{B\sin(\alpha)}{B\cos(\alpha) + A}))$$
equation(2):
$$A\sin(\omega t) - B\sin(\omega t + \alpha) = A\sin(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t + \alpha + 180^{o})$$
We can also rewrite a sine subtraction, as shown in equation 3, as a generic sine summation, making \$\beta = \alpha + 180^{o}\$ and measure the amplitude C in order to find the angle \$\alpha\$ as \$\beta\$ can be calculated through equation 4.
equation(3):
$$A\sin(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t + \beta) = C\sin(\omega t + \gamma)$$
equation(4)
$$\beta = \arccos(\frac{C^{2} - A^{2} - B^{2}}{2AB})$$
It's not important to calculate or measure the value of \$\gamma\$. A, the amplitude of the input signal will be taken as the refference, thus 0dB, its angle will also be a reference \$0^{o}\$, \$\beta\$ will be the angle of the output voltage, shifited \$180^{o}\$. C will be the RMS reading of VRMSdiff (from the block diagram), multiplied by \$\sqrt{2}\$. The idea is to generate sinusoidal signals within the audio range, of a known amplitude, then apply those signals to the DUT, measure the RMS value at the output and measure the differential RMS voltage (Vout – Vin). With those measurings, I though of computing them with Arduino or some other microcontroller, table them and plot a graph through Matlab or some math prohgramming language. So, I’m looking for suggestions as to what IC’s would work, with a good accuracy, as the sine generator (microcontroled VCO or DDS), a precise differential amplifier (maybe some INA) and a precise RMS-to-DC. Alternatively, I could use a precise differential RMS-to-DC, which would make it easier to measure the differential RMS value, as it would eliminate the need for a differential OP AMP.
P.S. all the sine equations was presented by Julius O. Smith III and can be found on his site: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Sum_Sinusoids_Same_Frequency.html
Or: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/635.php

I can think of a few easier ways than this just using a PC

D.A.S. can you please elaborate?

So, I’m looking for suggestions as to what IC’s would work <-- sounds like a shopping question

Make linear sweep for 30 s from 10 to 22kHz then make an attenuator pad to attenuate 1Vp signal to input and get 1Vp out . Calibrate it. Then insert DUT. plot the result using a log Spectrum Size1k , Rectangular Window .free software like Audacity.  Use Aux in out or Aux in Speaker out.  Use stereo jacks with adapters to your H/W

https://i.sstatic.net/Wl2siLwX.png

https://i.sstatic.net/trmwmWty.png
